# Error in hosting Django app with AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to host my Django app with AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
I took help from their very own documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-next-steps).
While I was deploying my app using `eb deploy` command it showed the below-mentioned error in my command prompt.

> ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).

## .ebextensions/django.config

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango/wsgi.py
```

## .ebextensions/db-migrate.config

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: ebdjango.settings
```

## settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'my-secret-key'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # installed apps
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'eshop',
    'product',
    'order',
    'user',
    'mptt',
    'paywix',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ebdjango.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ebdjango.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')

SITE_ID = 1


CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'images/'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = "pillow"

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': None,
    },
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'

PAYU_CONFIG = {
    "merchant_key": "key",
    "merchant_salt": "salt",
    "mode": "test",
    "success_url": "my success url",
    "failure_url": "my failure url",
}
```

Comment: Which Django version do you use? The minimum supported version of SQLite is increased to 3.8.3 in Django 2.2 and later. Try to upgrade your SQLite version or downgrade your Django version to latest Django 2.1.

Comment: Django==3.1.5
I can not downgrade my Django as lots of important dependencies won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try Upgrading your python to the version that supports the required SQLite version.

Run this command to see the current SQLite version:
`python3 -c "import sqlite3; print(sqlite3.sqlite_version)"`